# ¿Como llenar un arreglo de puros ceros?

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++

Yo usaba el for pero mis compañeros me dijeron que era mas fácil con un código que me mostraron, pero se me olvidó, yo recordaba

```
char[10]{0};
```

Pero no sale

Comment: puede ser de esta manera char arr[10] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

Comment: puse 10 de ejemplo, pero si el arreglo es de 100?

Answer (score 3):

Prueba esta variante en c++ para un arreglo de enteros:

```
int array[10]={0};
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de la anterior respuesta, también lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
int array[10] = {};
```

Comment: Si, con arreglos enteros si me funciona, y como puedo agregar elemento vacío en un char?

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), el elemento nulo del tipo char es '\0', por lo tanto, sí lo que quieres hacer es llenar un array tipo char de elementos nulos, lo puedes hacer así `char array[10] = {};`

Answer (score 1):

C++ dispone de tres estilos diferentes de inicialización de datos:

- **Por defecto**: El objeto realiza la rutina de inicialización por defecto, esto puede significar que el objeto no se inicializa. Para inicializar un arreglo por defecto, basta con declarar el arreglo:

  ```
  char datos[100];
  ```

  Esta inicialización deja los valores del arreglo con datos indeterminados.
- **Por valor**: El objeto se inicializa con un valor proveído. Para inicializar un arreglo por valor, deben darse valor a sus elementos:

  ```
  char datos[100] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  ```

  Esta inicialización asigna los valores proveídos, cualquier valor no proveído se inicializará a cero, en el ejemplo anterior las posiciones 0 a 5 tendrán los valores 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 y 6 mientras que las posiciones 6 a 99 tendrán el valor 0.
- **Por copia**: El objeto se inicializa copiando otro valor. Para inicializar un arreglo por copia, basta con igualarlo a unas llaves encerrando datos:

  ```
  char datos[100] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  ```

  Esta inicialización funciona como la inicialización por valor.

Estas inicializaciones funcionan de manera diferente dependiendo de si el arreglo es de objetos o de tipos fundamentales, si quieres saber las diferencias te animo a que redactes otra pregunta.

Si quieres inicializar una formación con ceros puros o impuros, usa la inicialización por valor o copia:

```
char datosA[100] { 0 };
char datosB[100] = { 0 };
```

Opcionalmente puedes usar unas llaves vacías y obtener el mismo resultado:

```
char datosA[100] {};
char datosB[100] = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Memset es tal vez una herramienta que estes buscando
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

> char str[100];
>
> memset (str,'0',100);